# How to set an Object's (JAVA) properties from different fragments which contain user input form fields in android?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

I have a POJO named Product who's json looks like this:

```
"products":[
    {
      "productId":"YCa18tCxRjOpAQ4HhCNZ",
      "availableQuantity":1550,
      "cartonQuanity":100,
      "categoryName":"Men's formals",
      "color":"red",
      "colorSelection":"red,green,blue",
      "description":"this is a nice shoe",
      "discountPrice":199.50,
      "images":[
        {
          "imageId":"XCHDYUE76uD&HGD", 
          "imageUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello"

        },
      {
        "imageId":"XCHDYUEFG76uD&HGD", 
        "imageUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello"
      }
      ],
      "isOutOfStock":false,
      "productName":"ZenStar Men's Canvas Shoes",
      "price":250,
      "setQuantity":6,
      "size":"8x2",
      "sizeSelection":"8x2,9x2,10x2",
      "soleName":"EVA",
      "sortTags":"men's formals, formal wear",
      "type":"men",
      "notes":"some note on this product",
      "videoUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello",
      "isShowOutOfStock":true,
      "isForceAllowOrder":true
  },
  {
      "productId":"YCa18tCxRjOpAQ4HhCNZ",
      "availableQuantity":1550,
      "cartonQuanity":100,
      "categoryName":"Men's formals",
      "color":"red",
      "colorSelection":"red,green,blue",
      "description":"this is a nice shoe",
      "discountPrice":199.50,
      "images":[
        {
          "imageId":"XCHDYUE76uD&HGD", 
          "imageUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello"

        },
      {
        "imageId":"XCHDYUEFG76uD&HGD", 
        "imageUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello"
      }
      ],
      "isOutOfStock":false,
      "productName":"ZenStar Men's Canvas Shoes",
      "price":250,
      "setQuantity":6,
      "size":"8x2",
      "sizeSelection":"8x2,9x2,10x2",
      "soleName":"EVA",
      "sortTags":"men's formals, formal wear",
      "type":"men",
      "notes":"some note on this product",
      "videoUrl":"https://fakeimage.org/376?q=hello",
      "isShowOutOfStock":true,
      "isForceAllowOrder":true
  }
  ]
```

and i have created respective JAVA classes for the same from jsonschema2pojo.org

Now the problem:

I have an activity which contains tablayout setup with viewpager with 3 fragments:
Fragment 1 contains a form with edittexts to get data from user for the above mentioned fields like: product name, color, size, etc.
Fragment 2 which contains some switches like: isOutOfStock, isForceAllowOrder, etc.
Fragment 3 which again has some fields associated with the product like: notes, pick more product images from gallery, pick product video, etc.

Now I want to set all this data filled by user in an instance of my Product class which also has getters and setters on the click of a button which is a menu item in a menu to be inflated for the parent activity of these 3 fragments.

This object when saved with all the user provided data is then to be saved to firebase realtime database or firestore

I am totally messed up understanding how to achieve this because:
1. I have tried communicating between fragments and activity via interfaces
2. I have tried passing objects between activities and fragments using serializable/parcelable and even gson
3. I have tried creating static instances of my Product class in a static class

but still i am unable to achieve saving data from different fragments to a common object instance

Please help. I will be really thankful to this great community of StackOverflow

I am posting the screenshots of my app to help you better understand the situation

[image: fragment 1]
[image: fragment 2]
[image: fragment 3]

Comment: the issuue is in view pager because viewpager by default set the offscreenlimit page atleast one means one fragment of right and one for left. so when viewpager is intitaliaze it creates the all three fragments. for your purpose use the simple recyclerview with snaphelper to get the view pager swi[pe. and attach to the tab layout listener.

Comment: I think i kinda solved it by using ViewModel android architectural components

Comment: yes MVVM architecture support this to do it.. because it ensure the loose coupling